# How to introduce new subelement node in an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7, elementtree

I am new to Python programming .
I have a xml file in which one snippet is as below .

```
<relationship name="a_to_b">
  <containment>
    <parent>
      <hasClass name="a" />
    </parent>
    <child>
      <hasClass name="b" />
    </child>
  </containment>
</relationship>
```

Now I have to update this section with the below content .

```
<relationship name="a_to_b">
  <containment>
    <parent>
      <hasClass name="a">
         <mimName>top</mimName>
       </hasClass>
    </parent>
    <child>
      <hasClass name="b">
        <mimName>top</mimName>
      </hasClass>
    </child>
  </containment>
</relationship>
```

I am using ElmentTree module .
How can I achieve this .
Python version 2.6 .

I am using below code .

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=xml) ;
root=tree.getroot() ;
print("Root tag of xml : "+root.tag) ;
#child_of_root=root;
#print("Root tag attribute of xml : "+root.attrib) ;



def fun(root):
   #if root.tag is not 'relationship':
      for child_of_root in root :
          #print("Tag : "+child_of_root.tag) ;
          attribut=child_of_root.attrib ;
          #print "Value : %s" %  attribut.get('name')
          if (child_of_root.tag == 'hasClass' and attribut.get('name') == 'MeContext') or (child_of_root.tag == 'hasClass' and attribut.get('name') == 'ManagedElement') :
           print(child_of_root.tag,attribut.get('name')) ;
           new_data = ET.SubElement(child_of_root, 'mimName');
           new_data.text = 'Top' 
       fun(child_of_root) 

fun(root);
```

Comment: Can anybody help here ?

Comment: Why is the question tagged "python-3.x" and "python-2.7" if you use Python 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement` to add tags within another tag. Copying from Python.org ->

```
>>> a = ET.Element('a')
>>> b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
>>> c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
>>> d = ET.SubElement(c, 'd')
>>> ET.dump(a)
<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>
```

Comment: Should I change the "new_data = ET.SubElement(child_of_root, 'mimName');" line with "new_data = xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(child_of_root, 'mimName');" .     I did the above one but getting  File "./test.py", line 26, in fun
    new_data = xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(child_of_root, 'mimName');
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'etree'
 error .

Comment: I'm running out of time. What I can tell you is, whenever you use qoutes `'' ` the type is string. However you are taking is as Tag in your code somewhere. Change that. Make sure you use `ET` only on tags and not a simple string.